# How to add menu to application in prism way in WPF application?

Tags: wpf, mvvm, prism

I have been following Prism reference implementation of stock trader app. I am building application following the same way. but I am bit confused at how I shall add menu to my application in Prism way. Reference implementation seems to be not clear cut on this. Any suggestion would be much appreciable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modular applications can help with many things, but they can also make some previously trivial tasks seem very difficult. I agree with you that the Prism book should at least give some examples on how to do a menu, but there are probably many ways to do it.

I asked the same question when I started with Prism on Stackoverflow. I came back some time later and answered my own question. My solution was to create an IMenuService that allowed me to add menu items to my menu, the menu is a separate module. Please see my answer to my own question here:

[DataTemplate to generate Menu with MVVM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9502680/datatemplate-to-generate-menu-with-mvvm)

Comment: do you have this source hosted somewhere for me to take a look

Comment: @kbird See the answer on that linked question now, I've updated it with a full example. File->Download should get you the Zip. I hope that helps!

Comment: @kbird Just curious, what do you think of that example? Do you think you'll do anything similar, or have you found another idea?

Comment: Thanks Alan, I was able to get it working based on your solution. Thanks for guidance. Appreciate a lot!

Answer (score 1):

To make a dynamic menu, I uses regions. The first thing I did in the `ShellView` was to add a menu and set a region in it.

```
<Menu prism:RegionManager.RegionName="MenuRegion">
</Menu>
```

When I need a menu in my module, I create a user control like this:

```
<MenuItem x:Class="MyCompany.PrismApp.HelloWorldMenu">
    <!-- ... -->
</MenuItem>
```

Change the code behind to let the class reflects the type `MenuItem`:

```
public partial class HelloWorldMenu : MenuItem
{
    // ...
}
```

The implementation of the `IModule`

```
public class SomeModule : IModule
{
    public void Initialize()
    {
        // ...
        this.RegionManager.RegisterViewWithRegion("MenuRegion", typeof(HelloWorldMenu));
    }
}
```

All is vanilla Prism.